# Word 2007 throws an exception for interop code that manipulates shapes but works fine in Word 2010

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm having big problems with a code that should add watermark pictures (used as stationery) to a document before saving it as PDF. Inserting the picture to all relevant headers is no problem. But as soon as I try to strech the picture (shape) to the whole page width and height, Word 2007 (SP3) throws an exception. The same code works fine in Word 2010 (SP1). It doesn't matter if I use the Office 12 or Office 14 interop assemblies (always used with "Embed Interop Types" true).

The exception thrown is the following:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A122C): Falscher Zeichnungselement-Typ für diesen Befehl.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape.set_RelativeHorizontalSize(WdRelativeHorizontalSize prop)
   at BEKO.PDB.AuxiliaryServices.Documents.WordCreationService.AddWatermarkToHeader(HeaderFooter header, String watermarkFilePath)
```

I don't know exactly what the english error message would be, but the translation is something like "Invalid painting type (or maybe shape type) for this command".

The weird thing is that it doesn't always error on the same interop call. If I remove the line that sets the `RelativeHorizontalSize` property it fails when setting another property, like `WidthRelative` (with the same exception). If I add a line that sets `shape.LeftRelative` (to the "do not use" constant) it even fails on a line that otherwise works like `shape.Top` (again with the same exception).

The code I'm using is from a macro that was recorded in the failing Word 2007. I'm also correctly switching to the header SeekView before executing any header related code because I already needed that for some other header/footer code.

Here is the full code that adds the shape. It should just insert the picture and strech it to the full page size. Note: This method is only called for headers that are actually existing (`headerFooter.Exists`) and that are not linked to the previous (`!headerFooter.LinkToPrevious`).

```
private static void AddWatermarkToHeader(HeaderFooter header, string watermarkFilePath) {
   header.Range.Editors.Add(WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);

   Shape shape = header.Shapes.AddPicture(
      FileName: watermarkFilePath,
      LinkToFile: false,
      SaveWithDocument: true
   );

   shape.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = (int)MsoTriState.msoTrue;
   shape.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapNone;

   shape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage;
   shape.RelativeVerticalPosition = WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage;
   shape.Left = 0;
   shape.Top = 0;

   shape.RelativeHorizontalSize = WdRelativeHorizontalSize.wdRelativeHorizontalSizePage;
   shape.RelativeVerticalSize = WdRelativeVerticalSize.wdRelativeVerticalSizePage;
   shape.WidthRelative = 100;
   shape.HeightRelative = 100;

   shape.ZOrder(MsoZOrderCmd.msoSendBehindText);
}
```

Please give any advice how to fix this so that the code works with both Word 2007 and Word 2010.

Comment: What is the watermark file format?

Comment: Have you tried the ScaleHeight/Width methods? Or the PickUp method? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape_methods.aspx

Comment: @Brannon The file is a JPG. I can't use ScaleHeight/Width since the original image might be of any size and I need it to exactly fill the whole page. How would the PickUp method help in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this does not *fix* the code to run on both versions of Word as requested, but have you tried using absolute sizing for the image instead? Keep relative positionning, but use absolute sizing. Do you actually need relative sizing (i.e. do your documents contain multiple page sizes?).

```
shape.Width = page.Width;
shape.Height = page.Height;
```

Comment: Great idea! I'm now using this workaround and it really prevents the exceptions. And by using the values from `section.PageSetup.PageWidth/PageHeight` it should even work for different page sizes in one document. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is a completely fresh look at the problem ... rather that a narrow focus on one perceived solution. Glad this simple workaround helped, and thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

From Word 97 through to Word 2003 there has been a little known bug in the Word Object Model that causes `WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage` and `WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage` to retrieve the incorrect information if the magnification of the active Word document in not 100%. I suspect that this issue still exists in Word 2007 and may be causing your exception. Here are two threads (both dealing with the same issue in VBA) that refer to this issue:

[Points-returned-by-Information-wdHorizontalPositionSubroutines](http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/word-vba/10347/Points-returned-by-Information-wdHorizontalPositionSubroutines)

[Word 97 wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/microsoft.public.word.word97vba/wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage/microsoft.public.word.word97vba/AZnLbq2saFQ/-WoUnPmyZXQJ)

I suggest adding code after the addition of the shape in the header (and prior to retrieving the relative horizontal and vertical positions to the page) that changes the Active Document's zoom to 100% and the View Type to the Print Layout view. (You may have to experiment with which part of the Word document is displayed when the code for changing the positioning and sizing of the shape is executed. Sometimes it will be necessary for the Active Document to display/be able to edit the main document instead of the header.)

Comment: Thanks for that information, but it seems like that isn't the problem. I still get the same exception when I make sure that the document is opened with 100% zoom and I also still get the exception if I add the following code to my application: `_application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Zoom.Percentage = 100;` I already have code that switches to Print Layout view because this is needed for some other operations.